How do I fix puppeteer sending message duplicated?
So, I made a whatsapp message sender in nodejs using puppeteer to connect to wpp and electron to get the message and number inputs, but I have three main problems:

It doesnt send the message after everything is loaded;
When the message finally gets sent, it sends it duplicated;
Most of the times, it takes too long to load and send message.

main.js below
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const timeout = require('node:timers/promises');

let mainWindow;
let browser;
let page;

async function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'src/preload.js'),
            contextIsolation: true,
            enableRemoteModule: false
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadFile('src/index.html');
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

ipcMain.handle('connect-whatsapp', async () => {
    try {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
        page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://web.whatsapp.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        await page.waitForSelector('#side', { timeout: 120000 });
        return 'Conexão bem-sucedida. Você pode enviar mensagens agora.';
    } catch (error) {
        return `Erro ao conectar ao WhatsApp: ${error.message}`;
    }
});

ipcMain.handle('send-message', async (event, numbers, message) => {
    if (!browser || !page) {
        return 'Erro: Navegador ou página não inicializados.';
    }

    try {
        const responses = [];
        for (const number of numbers) {
            const url = `https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${number.trim()}&text=${encodeURIComponent(message)}`;
            await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
            console.log(`Iniciando conversa com ${number.trim()}`);

            await page.waitForSelector('#main > footer > div._ak1k._ahmw.copyable-area > div > span:nth-child(2) > div > div._ak1r > div._ak1l > div > div > p', { timeout: 60000 });
            await page.type('#main > footer > div._ak1k._ahmw.copyable-area > div > span:nth-child(2) > div > div._ak1r > div._ak1l > div > div > p', message);
            await page.click('#main > footer > div._ak1k._ahmw.copyable-area > div > span:nth-child(2) > div > div._ak1r > div._ak1t._ak1u > button > span', {delay: 200}); // Adiciona um pequeno atraso para garantir que o botão seja clicado corretamente
            await timeout.setTimeout(2000);

            responses.push(`Mensagem enviada para ${number.trim()}`);
        }
        return responses;
    } catch (error) {
        return `Erro ao enviar mensagens: ${error.message}`;
    }
});


preload.js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    connectWhatsApp: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('connect-whatsapp'),
    sendMessage: (numbers, message) => ipcRenderer.invoke('send-message', numbers, message)
});


and the renderer.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const connectButton = document.getElementById('connectButton');
    const broadcastForm = document.getElementById('broadcastForm');
    const responseContainer = document.getElementById('responseContainer');
    const cancelButton = document.getElementById('cancelButton');

    connectButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        try {
            const status = await window.electronAPI.connectWhatsApp();
            console.log(status);

            if (status.startsWith('Conexão bem-sucedida')) {
                broadcastForm.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                alert(status);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Erro ao conectar ao WhatsApp:', error);
        }
    });

    broadcastForm.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const numbers = document.getElementById('numbers').value.split(',');
        const message = document.getElementById('message').value;

        if (numbers.length > 0 && message) {
            try {
                const responses = await window.electronAPI.sendMessage(numbers, message);
                console.log(responses);
                responseContainer.innerHTML = '';
                responses.forEach(response => {
                    const p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.textContent = response;
                    responseContainer.appendChild(p);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erro ao enviar mensagens:', error);
            }
        } else {
            alert('Por favor, insira números de telefone e uma mensagem.');
        }
    });
    cancelButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        window.close();
    });
});


anyone have any ideas?
